# How to print at a specific z-index?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, z-index

Currently trying to get a completed form to print. Once the user completes the form and clicks "complete form", a popup modal comes up with options to download, print, and logout. Modal is at z-index 1 and form is at z-index 0. When trying to use window.print(), it only shows the modal since it has a higher z-index. Is there any way I can get it to print only what is at z-index of 0?

Answer (score 0):

You can add specific CSS declarations for printing and disable the modal.

```
@media print { 
  .modal { 
    display: none !important; 
   } 
}
```

But there is no way to specify a "print level" with pure CSS. This would also make no sense, since there may are different stacking contexts, depending on how your CSS is built. An element with `z-index: 5` can still be below an `z-index: 1` element, if they both belong to different stacking contexts.